# Finding Roots of a Function

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

I'm very new to *Mathematica*.

I am trying to find the roots of a function in terms of `t`, here is my try and the output:

```
p[y_, t_, k_] := ((1 - E^(-((-1 + y)^2/t))) t)/(-1 + y)^2 - 
                ((1 - E^(-((1 + y)^2/t))) t)/(1 + y)^2 - k

FindRoot[p[y, t, 0.5], {y, 1}]

During evaluation of In[3]:= Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0.^2 encountered. >>

During evaluation of In[3]:= Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. t ComplexInfinity encountered. >>

During evaluation of In[3]:= FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {Indeterminate} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {y} = {1.}. >>

(* FindRoot[p[y, t, 0.5], {y, 1}] *)
```

I also tried `NSolve`:

```
p[y_, t_, k_]:= ((1 - E^(-((-1 + y)^2/t))) t)/(-1 + y)^2 - 
                ((1 - E^(-((1 + y)^2/t))) t)/(1 + y)^2 - k

t = Table[i, {i, 0, 5}]
NSolve[p[y, t, 0.5], y]
```

but got error messages about division by zero. However, I am suspecting the starting value for `y = 1`, which will then evolve with time `t`. I will appreciate any insight into solving for `Roots` of this type of equation.

Comment: You pass `1` as the initial value for `y` in `FindRoot`, when your function has `-1+y` in the denominator -- shouldn't you expect a divide by zero error?

Comment: Indeed one would expect zero, however, the function is such that the starting value for 'y=1' at 't=0', which then evolves with time. Beyond 't~3.75', solution no longer exist for the function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) by restricting the domain to [`Reals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reals.html) and specifying a [`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) rather than using [`MachinePrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MachinePrecision.html)

```
p[y_, t_, k_] :=
  ((1 - E^(-((-1 + y)^2/t))) t)/(-1 + y)^2 -
   ((1 - E^(-((1 + y)^2/t))) t)/(1 + y)^2 - k;
```

Including verification of the solution

```
Module[{soln},
  {"t=" <> ToString[#, TraditionalForm],
     soln = NSolve[p[y, #, 1/2] == 0, y, Reals,
       WorkingPrecision -> 15],
     If[Length[soln] > 0, And @@ (p[y, #, 1/2] == 0 /. soln),
      $Failed]} & /@
   Range[1/2, 4, 1/2]] // Grid
```

[image]

**EDIT:**  Plotting contour for `p[y, t, 1/2] == 0`

Finding the approximate `{t, y}` point for the largest value of `t`

```
pt1 = FindArgMax[{t, p[y, t, 1/2] == 0},
  {{t, 3.5}, {y, 1.8}}]

(*  {3.76655, 1.87905}  *)
```

Finding the approximate `{t, y}` point for the smallest value of `t`

```
pt2 = FindArgMin[{t, p[y, t, 1/2] == 0, t >= 0},
   {{t, 1/100}, {y, 99/100}},
   WorkingPrecision -> 20] // N

(*  {9.58573*10^-9, 0.999876}  *)
```

`ContourPlot` with extreme points

```
ContourPlot[p[y, t, 1/2] == 0,
 {t, 0, 3.8}, {y, 0.4, 2.35},
 Exclusions -> {t == 0},
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {t, y}),
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[{pt1, pt2}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Bob for the clarification, Indeed the function has two roots at every given time except at t = 0, where y1=y2=1 and at t~3.75 with y1=y2~1.91. These were values given by an author for the problem. I have used your code to generate all the needed values.I will eventually have to generate some kind of plots with the solution set. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your starting point is more at `0.5` than `1` (at least for $t\in(0,1)$:

```
ContourPlot[p[y, t, 0.5], {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
Table[y /. FindRoot[p[y, i, 0.5], {y, 0.5}], {i, 0.1, 1, 0.1}]
```

> {0.625639, 0.514341, 0.460898, 0.438802, 0.434756, 0.44139, 0.454654, \
>   0.472282, 0.492957, 0.515882}

But:

[image]

so

```
Table[y /. FindRoot[p[y, i, 0.5], {y, 0.5 i}], {i, {1, 2.1, 3}}]
```

> {0.515882, 0.846635, 1.21487}

There appears to be some problem (probably with the convergence of the method) at `t = 2`, so I took `2.1` instead.

The `1/0` warning is related to the initial point; see [the docs for a description](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/General/infy.html).

Comment: Thanks @ Corey979. I wanted to find the values of y as a function of t as demonstrated by Bob Halon. For every given time, there are two values for y except at times t =0 and t~3.75. Some of the roots you generated are also listed in Bob's answer.